# ng-disabled is not working with respect to the values in column data field

Tags: angularjs

I want to disabled the button `Dissolve` if the field in the status column is close or vise versa.

I tried applying ng-module `n ng- disabled` but something went wrong.

If anybody knows how to do it in Angularjs then plz help me out

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Ticketid</th>
        <th>status</th>
        <th>Dissolve</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12345</td>
        <td>Close</td>
        <td><button>Dissolve</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4321</td>
        <td>open</td>
        <td><button>Dissolve</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Try [disabled] property

Comment: And explain bit more or paste your real code and what you have try then its better to answer.

Comment: table>
    <tr>
        <th>Ticketid</th>
        <th>status</th>
        <th>Dissolve</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12345</td>
        <td>Close</td>
        <td><button>Dissolve</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4321</td>
        <td>open</td>
        <td><button>Dissolve</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>

Comment: This is the real code real code if the value in status column is close then i want to disabled the button in dissolve column

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676784/how-to-disable-a-button-in-angularjs

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/LmaW7MomYpKyvKRkwyzU?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ng-if and ng-disabled together,

```
 <tr>
    <td>4321</td>
    <td>open</td>
    <td ng-if="status ==='close'"><button ng-disabled="true">Dissolve</button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: its just a sample you need to check for your condition. produce a plunker

Comment: Here is the plunker created by me

Comment: your plunker has nothing

Comment: @ManishaChavan only two rows in the table i.e hardcoded?

Comment: where does the status come from? where is your controller?